# Do kubernetes pods enter Terminating during or after preStop hook call?

Tags: kubernetes

I originally posted this on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77842994) but it was suggested I cross post here.

OK my real requirement is about graceful termination. I have a pod that implements a service via a grpc interface. Calls into the service can take some time - they are CPU intensive. All fairly good until a pod is recycled. What we want to happen is that we get no new traffic on a pod but any existing query continues to the end - we don't want immediate shutdown.

I've tried following the scheme in https://engineering.rakuten.today/post/graceful-k8s-delpoyments/ but without the SIGTERM handling. Perhaps I've misunderstood the reasoning for that and for the
preStop sleep call but at least my first understanding was the point of the sleep is to allow any existing calls to terminate. However in the kubernetes documentation it says:

> [If a container has a preStop hook configured, this hook runs before the container enters the Terminated state](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-state-terminated)

Does that mean that the container enters Terminated state when the preSleep hook returns or sometime after it has been called, effectively concurrently? The distinction is important because (I understand) if the container is Terminated, then the pod will not be Ready and it should get no new traffic.

I am further contemplating making the scheme more complicated so that a file is created on preStop and if this file exists this the readiness probe returns False - that should stop the traffic. However it seems wrong I should need to do this.

Have I missed something?